# Switch apps iOS can't change default launch icon

Tags: ios, flutter, dart, mobile, icons

How to change icon on switch apps on iOS (screenshot). I can't change this icon. I created cordova app, flutter app and clear swift iOS app. Every this solution don't change this icon.

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Create icons using this [link](https://www.google.com/url?sa=t&rct=j&q=&esrc=s&source=web&cd=&cad=rja&uact=8&ved=2ahUKEwjKlYXF_NbrAhVGyDgGHQG3BeQQFjABegQICxAB&url=https%3A%2F%2Fmakeappicon.com%2F&usg=AOvVaw3dXHzU5VoImWynS-w61mHp) and try to add them to your app

Answer (score 0):

For IOS you need to add your icon in the IOS Project (you have the XCTAsset file for add all icon), not in pubspec.yaml.